# Multiple instances of a foreign key under the same primary key instance

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

Sorry in advance, I am having a really hard time putting my question into real words. I think I may be fundamentally misunderstanding how foreign keys work. My question is as follows:

Am I able to call multiple foreign keys, that all come from the same table, under a specific primary key in another table in SQL or databases in general? For instance, I may have 3 tables: diagnosis_codes (PK = diag_code), diagnosis(PK = diag_id, FK = diag_code(references diagnosis_codes)), and encounter(PK = encounterId, FK = diag_id (references diagnosis)). I am wondering if I can have my diagnosis table accept as many (diag_code)s as I want in the form of foreign keys (e.g. diag_id: 1 could have diag_code 1,2,4,6,12,13 all in it and diag_id: 2 may have diag_code 1,2,3 under it).

My goal here is guess is to have a list of codes in one table and have a secondary table that can accept any number of those codes per instance (or per primary key instance) so that a tertiary table can cleanly reference a group of items as 1 id.

Right now, my tables would look something like:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS diagnosis_code;
    CREATE TABLE diagnosis_code (
        diag_code INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
    );


    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Diagnosis;
    CREATE TABLE diagnosis (
        diag_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
        diag_code INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (diag_code) REFERENCES diagnosis_code(diag_code)
    );
```

And I am wondering if, set up like this, I can accept multiple diag_codes per diag_id, and if not, if there is a way to say that each diagnosis can accept multiple diagnosis codes.

Any assistance with this issue would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The way you set it up, you can only accept one diag_code per diag_id. It's what is called a 1:1 relation between the two. To make it a 1:n relation (1 diag_id to multiple [n] diag codes), you need a separate table, for instance diagnoses, where you have a compound key made from the diag_id and diag_code. There you can have as many (diag_id, diag_code) pairs as you want.

Comment: Show some example data.